# modelBuilder.Query() is overwritten by scaffolding

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have an MVC Core (2.2) application with Entity Framework Core(database first). I use Scaffold-DbContext statement to generate my model classes from the database. Now, I need to get data from an sql view, besides tables. I do it by manually adding the following to OnModelCreating() of the db context class:

```
modelBuilder.Query<SomeModel>().ToView("vwSomeView");
```

When I need to make a change (update) in the database schema, I run Scaffold-DbContext, and the above code gets overwritten and disappears. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a partial class of your DbContext class. In that partial class, you can define your own `OnModelCreating()`.

```
protected void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder... )
{
    modelBuilder.Query<SomeModel>().ToView("vwSomeView");
    OnModelCreatingBase(modelBuilder);
}
```

In your scaffolded class, you would rename `OnModelCreating` to `OnModelCreatingBase`.

There is still manual work involved each time you scaffold your entities, but you get a compile time error after running the generator because OnModelCreating is declared twice. This is preferable to the runtime error you would otherwise experience.